# Display only enabled products in magento my wishlist

Tags: magento, status, product

When users login and click on my wishlist link it display the products. But it display the disabled products also. I want to display only the enabled products in wishlist.
Can any one suggest me how to make changes in code so that it will display only enabled products in my wishlist area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to extend this class `Mage_Wishlist_Model_Wishlist` and override the method `getItemCollection` by adding a filter by status. Something like this (untested, just added the last method call):

```
$this->_itemCollection =  Mage::getResourceModel('wishlist/item_collection')
             ->setStoreId($this->getStore()->getId())
             ->addWishlistFilter($this)
             ->addAttributeToFilter(
                 'status',
                  array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
             );
```

Note that this would exclude the disabled products every time you load the collection of Wishlist items, not only from the wishlist page, but also from potentially any place where you are displaying it, which I think is what you want.

Comment: Yes i want to display only enabled products in every where.
But the code is not working provide by you. I got thiserror when i use it.
Call to undefined method Mage_Wishlist_Model_Resource_Item_Collection::setStoreId()

If i comment setStoreId() line than it display this error
Call to undefined method Mage_Wishlist_Model_Resource_Item_Collection::addAttributeToFilter()

Comment: Try with `addFieldToFilter` instead of `addAttributeToFilter`?

Comment: Still getting the error
Unknown column 'status' in 'where clause'

Comment: I'm afraid I can't test this right now. I'd advice you to check this method Mage_Wishlist_Model_Resource_Item_Collection:: _assignProducts, at the end there is a loop loading the products, you can check there the status and and skip the disabled ones. I hope it helps!